# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments tips on function with "variable" number of arguments

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gis

The function is from an external library, I have no access to its source, but here is its documentation : http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-transform.htm

It claims to have two functions but with the same signature, but Oracle gives me the error (wrongfully I'm assuming) in title and won't let me compile the function.

Is there a way I can just skip this error and make it compile my function below? Because I am assuming on execution this error won't come.

Or am I really missing something?

Function :

```
create or replace function transform_to_utm_sul_x(fuso varchar,shape st_geometry)
RETURN number 
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS
    utm_x  number;
    srid INTEGER;
begin
    SELECT
        wkid_sul
    INTO
        srid
    FROM
        limt_fusos_utm
    WHERE
        zone = fuso and srid is not null and srid <> '';
    utm_x := st_x(st_transform(shape, srid));
    return utm_x;
end transform_to_utm_sul_x;
```

Stack trace :

> Error(16,47): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments tips in call to
>   'ST_TRANSFORM_F'

Comment: can you provide the error message and the error line please?

Comment: @TedFilippidis edited it

Comment: the only thing I can thing is that you are providing wrong type of data types into ST_TRANSFORM_F, can you provide the signature(s)?

Comment: Is the datatype, st_geometry, defined in schema where you are trying to compile this function?

Comment: @PatrickBacon that was one of the issues, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call st_transform with shape which is st_geometry and srid which is INTEGER.
Oracle says there is no matching definition of ST_TRANSFORM_F with types (st_geometry, integer). Or more precisely Oracle cannot convert parameters with actual types (st_geometry, integer) to any of existing definition of ST_TRANSFORM_F.

Quick demonstration.

```
SQL> create or replace function ST_TRANSFORM_F(i in integer) return integer
  2  as begin return 1; end;
  3  /

Function created.

SQL> create or replace function f(p in sys.odcinumberlist) return integer as
  2  begin return ST_TRANSFORM_F(p); end;
  3  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> sho err
Errors for FUNCTION F:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/7      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
2/14     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
         'ST_TRANSFORM_F'

SQL> create or replace function f(p in number) return integer as
  2  begin return ST_TRANSFORM_F(p); end;
  3  /

Function created.
```

number can be converted to integer but sys.odcinumberlist, for example, cannot.

Comment: That was one of the issues, another is that it was SDE.st_geometry